# MySQL join multiple rows into one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, logic

I need to create an SQL statement to join multiple rows into one column.  I have three table which are shown below.  I need to join them all to get 1 row for each product (i.e. group by products.id).

There can be up to 6 images per product in the products_images table.  I need a column for each image even if there are no product images.

```
Products Table
---
id
product_name
supplier_id


Suppliers Table
---
id
company_name


Product Images Table
---
id
product_id
fullsize
```

Here is an example dump of what i'm trying to achieve:

```
id  product_name   company_name  image1     image2     image3     image4     image5     image6
1   Ballpoint pen  Impression    img/1.jpg  img/2.jpg  img/3.jpg  img/4.jpg  img/5.jpg  null
2   T-shirt        Impression    img/6.jpg  img/7.jpg  img/8.jpg  null       null       null
3   Jumper         Impression    null       null       null       null       null       null
```

As you can see the first product has 5 images, second product has 3 and last product has 0 images.

How can I achieve the above result?

Thanks!

Comment: From your question it seems like you need to combine the image1,2,3.. into one string if so use group_concant(). but from the example you have it seems that you want to convert rows into column if this is the case you are looking at Pivot tables (check this url http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-table-with-dynamic-columns/)

Comment: Google "mysql dynamic pivot".  A SQL query has to have a fixed number of columns, so unless you know the number of columns when you write the query, you need to do something more sophisticated, such as a `prepare`/`execute` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I've already looked into pivot tables but can't figure out how to use them in my scenario.

Comment: I'd second the idea that you should use a pivot option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into using CASE statements.

For instance.

```
SELECT id,
 product_name,
 company_name,
 CASE WHEN Product Images Table.id = 1  THEN image1 ELSE NULL END AS image1,
 CASE WHEN Product Images Table.id = 2  THEN image1 ELSE NULL END AS image2
 ....
 FROM Products Table
 JOIN Suppliers Table
 JOIN Product Images Table
```

Comment: I tried your code (changed it a bit) but it doesn't return the desired result. Not sure your code will work as there are thousands of images in the products_table and it would take thousands of CASE statements to make that work.  Here's the code I used:

Comment: SELECT 
products.id,
 products.product_name,
 suppliers.company_name,
 CASE WHEN products_images.id = 1  THEN fullsize ELSE NULL END AS image1,
 CASE WHEN products_images.id = 2  THEN fullsize ELSE NULL END AS image2
 FROM products 
 JOIN suppliers 
 JOIN products_images

Comment: To be of more help, I need to know how the image table relates to the product table and how the images relate to image_number.  If you don't have image numbers on the table, you could try six joins back to the image table, but that's probably going to take a long time to run.

Comment: There is no image_number field in the products_images table.  How would six joins back to the table look?  Is there a faster way?

Comment: In answer to your first question: the image table relates to the products table by "product_id" (linking it to products.id).